# R: invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: list, r, subscript

I'm trying to use the indices of a sorted column of a dataset.  I want to reorder the entire dataset by one sorted column.

```
area.sort<-sort(xsample$area1, index.return=TRUE)[2]
```

The output is a list, so I can't use it index through the whole dataset.

```
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Someone suggested using unlist but I can't get rid of the `ix*`.
Any ideas?  Thanks

```
> area.sort<-unlist(area.sort)

 ix1   ix2   ix3   ix4   ix5   ix6   ix7   ix8   ix9  ix10  ix11  ix12  ix13 
  45    96    92    80    53    54    24    21    63    81    40    66    64
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The call to sort with index.`return=TRUE` returns a list with two components: x and ix. Indexing with [2] returns a subset of the list - still a list.

If you index using [[2]] it should work better. That returns the element in the list.
But indexing using $ix is perhaps a bit clearer.

But then again, if you only need the sorted indices, you should call `order` instead of `sort`...

Comment: +1 for mentioning `order`, which is what they probably want instead.

Comment: Awesome, order works well;

 and the double brackets work well too, thanks